# Germany - Non EU Citizen with Blue Card employment looking to start Freelance on the side

Tags: germany, labor-law

I am a non EU citizen living in Germany with a Blue Card - not tied to an employer - and a Zusatzblatt that allows me to take up freelance activities.

My Employer has no clauses in my contract that restricts me from taking up freelance roles. Additionally, I do plan to notify them of my freelance activity just to be on the safer side, and I believe they will be ok with it - based on my discussions with my colleagues, boss etc.

Having said that, how many hours of Freelance work am I Legally permitted to take up? Is there a limit on how much I am allowed to earn?